# Select area which is at least x meters away from other geometries

Tags: postgis, postgresql, polygon, postgis-2.0, query

In my table I have the build-up area from a region as a big number of polygons.

> urban_area: id | name | geometry(polygon)

I was wondering if and how I would be able to find the area within a bounding box that is at least x-meters away from any geometry in the `urban_area` table. In  schematics:

[image]

With the orange being the geometry in `urban_area`, the grey the offset and the dotted area the desired area.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this. Buffer and union all the polygons that fall in the box, then subtract that from the box:

```
WITH buffers AS (
  SELECT ST_Union(ST_Buffer(mypoly.geom, radius)) AS theunion FROM mypoly
  WHERE mypoly.geom && ST_MakeEnvelope(minx,miny,maxx,maxy)
)
SELECT ST_Difference(ST_MakeEnvelope(minx,miny,maxx,mazy), theunion)
FROM buffers;
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure this will work but take a look at [ST_Difference](http://postgis.org/docs/ST_Difference.html) in PostGIS. It doesn't take a geometry collection.

1. Create a polygon that covers the entire area of interest.
2. Merge the buffered areas/polygons into a single feature.
3. Use ST_Difference to return the non-intersected part of the geometry from 1.